# This indication is showing on my dashboard, am I sensing danger?

Tags: maintenance

My car shows -91km service overdue,  what do I do. I  have no money right now.Is there anything I can do? It's a 2013-Honda Civc. Mensah.

Comment: If you do nothing else, change the engine oil and filter when you can, but it's probably not dangerously urgent. However, you should get a free brake and tyre safety test if available.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The car is telling you a service is overdue ... do you know which service is overdue? How many KMs on your Honda?